# RESET Test - omitted variable not significant in model

Tags: regression, error

I have a linear model with 4 independent variables.

To confirm that there are not omitted nonlinear variables left out, I ran the **RESET test**. It turned out that a multiplication by two variables (A*B) is highly significant. 
Therefore I also included it in the model such that there are now 5 independent where one is a multiplication of two. (A*B)

However, when I now run the entire regression of the model again, the A*B term is not significant anymore. Therefore I need to remove it again. 
Why is it like that? I know that the RESET test sometimes can be flawed.